# functional equation that relates $\psi(x,\chi)$ and $\psi(x^{-1},\overline{\chi})$.

Tags: analytic-number-theory

On Davenport's Multiplicative Number Theory, Page $68$, It tried to derive a functional equation that relates $\psi(x,\chi)$ and $\psi(x^{-1},\overline{\chi})$. However I am stuck. I tried using the definitions but cannot understand.

How it writes the equality

$$\tau(\overline{\chi})\psi(x,\chi)=\sum_{m=1}^{q} \overline{\chi}(m) \sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty} e^{-n^2 \pi x/q+ 2 \pi i mn/q}$$

Comment: such things typically come from the Poisson summation formula

Comment: since  they defined the gauss sum and derived some equalites, I am looking for explaination that uses concept from that chapter only

Comment: hmm, are you sure it doesn't come straight from the definitions?  could you write both definitions down in the post, just to be absolutely sure we're not missing anything? (if i'm not mistaken, you need definitions (6) and (7) from that page)

Comment: @tomos, I was not getting it earlier. I wrote down the expression for the $\psi(x,\chi)$ and took the gaussian sum inside and then I used $(6)$.